# Why were they keeping the mother from helping the daughter in Mary Shelley's Frankenstein?

Tags: frankenstein, mary-shelley

> Elizabeth  had  caught  the  scarlet  fever;  her  illness  was  severe,  and she  was  in  the  greatest  danger.  During  her  illness  many  arguments  had  been  urged  to  persuade  my  mother  to  refrain from  attending  upon  her.  She  had  at  first  yielded  to  our  entreaties,  but  when  she  heard  that  the  life  of  her  favourite was  menaced,  she  could  no  longer  control  her  anxiety.  She attended  her  sickbed;  her  watchful  attentions  triumphed over  the  malignity  of  the  distemper—Elizabeth  was  saved, but  the  consequences  of  this  imprudence  were  fatal  to  her preserver.  On  the  third  day  my  mother  sickened

Why were they keeping the mother from helping the daughter? Is this a contagious disease or I missed something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Wikipedia entry on scarlet fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_fever), I don't know if this is really related, but it is a bacterial infection. Considering that at the time the story goes there were no antibiotics, I might be mistaken on this one but I think people didn't even used to wash hands when handling sick people, I don't know how people were educated though, but that would improve the chances of someone getting sick. Contracting it could be potentially fatal. As it says in the Wikipedia article, it was a major cause of infant mortality in the early 20th century.